# Transform a view by dragging its edge (Swift)

Tags: swift, drawing

I try to make an app where the user can draw or add an arrow, and transform this arrow (translate, rotate, ...).
For the moment, I manage to draw the arrow and make all the transformations on it, but what I would like to do now is to be able to modify the arrow by dragging its edges.

To draw an arrow, I just create a UIView with a height of 20px (it is the thickness of the arrow), and a width of 400 (length of the arrow).

```
func drawArrow(frame: CGRect) {
    let thicknessArrow = 20
    let viewHorizontalArrow = UIView()
    viewHorizontalArrow.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 600)
    viewHorizontalArrow.frame.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: thicknessArrow)

    drawDoubleArrow(viewHorizontalArrow, startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: thicknessViewWithArrow/2), endPoint: CGPoint(x: viewHorizontalArrow.frame.width, y: thicknessViewWithArrow/2), lineWidth: 10, color: UIColor.blackColor())

}
```

After that, I transform the UIView thanks to the pan, pinch and rotate gesture.

The function "drawDoubleArrow" create an arrow with BezierPath and add it to the layer of the UIView.

I hope these explanations are clear enough :).

Could you help me to find a solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you post your code for the arrows? It's hard to help without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added how I create the arrow (which is a layer in a UIView that I transform :)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I'll post an answer and if it isn't something that works for you, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm able to move the arrow thanks to your code, but what I would like to do is to be able to touch one end of the arrow, then by moving the finger on the screen, the end of the arrow that I touched would follow my finger. Any clues ? :)

Comment: I would have thought my code did that. (1) You are talking about a pan gesture here, correct? (2) If so, what is happening? If you are talking something other than a pan, there are options.

Comment: Yes indeed. But if I touch an end of the arrow and move the finger, it should  transform the arrow, because the other end of the arrow mustn't move. Sorry, maybe it's not really clear ^^

Comment: I don't want this to move into chat. I now get it - you want the arrow stem to *grow*, not just *move*. Let me think this over and I'll either edit my answer or remove it, depending. I would suggest you edit your question. Maybe adding the word "grow" or "lengthen" to it? Off the top of my head, maybe have 2 views with respective layers. One that moves and one that grows - that might be pretty simple using auto layout. Are you (using auto layout)?

Answer (score 0):

`UIBezierPath` on it's own cannot easily be manipulated by gestures because it doesn't recognize them. But a `UIView` can recognize gestures. Combined with a `CALayer`'s ability to be transformed and it's `hitTest()` method, I think you can achieve what you want.

```
// I'm declaring the layer as a shape layer, but depending on how your error thick is, you may need a rectangular one
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var myLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

**viewDidLoad:**

```
// I'm assuming you've created myBezierPath, an arrow path
myLayer.path = myBezierPath.cgPath

// Adding the pan gesture to the view's controller
panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveLayer))
self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

**moveLayer:**

```
func moveLayer(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)

    // You will want to loop through all the layers you wish to transform
    if myLayer.hitTest(p) != nil {
        myLayer.position = p
    }
}
```